# Smartgwt Drop from listgrid to treegrid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to get the event when the user left a record from a listgrid on a treenode in treegrid.

I was trying with

```
ListGrid messagesGrid = new ListGrid();
messagesGrid.setCanDrag(true);

TreeGrid shortcutsTreeGrid = new TreeGrid();
shortcutsTreeGrid.setCanAcceptDrop(true);
shortcutsTreeGrid.setCanAcceptDroppedRecords(true);

shortcutsTreeGrid.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {
@Override
public void onDrop(DropEvent dropEvent) {
       SC.say("drop event is called"); // I want to catch this event

 }
});
```

Please any idea?

Comment: What problem are you facing with this code?

Comment: onDrop's TreeGrid can't catch a record from messageGrid

Comment: Can't you use the selected Record of **messageGrid**? Ultimately selected Record of **messageGrid** is going to be dropped on **shortcutsTreeGrid**.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use addFolderDropHandler() when dropping onto a TreeGrid.

For example

```
treeGrid.addFolderDropHandler(new FolderDropHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onFolderDrop(FolderDropEvent folderDropEvent) {
      SC.say("folder dropped");
  }
}
```